# Reducing size of png using pngquant applicatipon

Tags: png, libpng, 24-bit, pngquant

i have millions of map tiles as png format. All  files in subdirectories like 0/0/0.png,1.png...

how can i reduce size of my all png using pngquant batch command

Comment: I assume from your "24bit" tag that your images are 24-bit RGB PNGs.  I don't know what to make of your "libpng" tag.  Can you post a sample image?

Comment: Well, with no sample image I just guess you are using Google map tiles.  This works on screen grabs from a Google map on screen:"for x in file.png;do;pngquant 31 $x;done"; run that in each directory.  Revise this script to descend into each directory and run it.  The resulting files will have names "1-fs8.png", etc.  You may observe slight discontinuities at the tile boundaries because the quantized palette might be different in each tile.  If you are indeed using Google map tiles I'll make this an answer.